# SPFx app not showing up in the webpart list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

As I am new to SharePoint Framework, I am trying to update an existing web-part (updated the version in `package-solution.json`).

Updated `.sppkg` file in app catalog (overwrite), shows new version number.
Go to collection where the existing web-part was working, update to new version and nothing works.

The web-part isn't showing up anymore.

Please suggest any workaround.

This is my package-solution.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "tms-client-side-solution",
    "id": "6c0b762c-5c8c-4bf5-9094-f3c39f865b8d",
    "version": "3.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "developer": {
      "name": "",
      "websiteUrl": "",
      "privacyUrl": "",
      "termsOfUseUrl": "",
      "mpnId": ""
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/tms.sppkg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed the updated version via the app catalog?

Comment: No ...I have updated the version directly through package-solution.json file

Comment: I have added an answer for your question which will hopefully allow you to update your app.

Comment: I have to run this command in PnP Powershell?

Comment: Yes, my answer refers to PnP PowerShell

Comment: I have run this command on PnP PowerShell..

Answer (score 0):

[Update-PnPApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/update-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps) updates an installed app if a new version is available in the tenant or site collection app catalog.

Comment: This solution gives following error:  Error: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.current/web/sitecollectionappcatalog/."}}}

Comment: Have you specified the correct ID? Also, is your solution in a tenant or site collection app catalog?

Comment: Yes I have specified correct ID...solution is in site collection app catalog..Please suggest other workaround..

Comment: You may need to deploy the solution to your site again if it isn't showing up at all. The PowerShell works if the solution is already deployed and a new version is added to the app catalog.

Comment: PowerShell is also not working...I have added the new version of app to the app catalog...Same appI am able to add in my site collection but it is not getting shown up at the time of adding webpart to the site pages..